# jquery edit table data not getting text value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a table where user can edit every row but the problem is that when i click on edit the fields are not changing and also it is not getting the text value for each row in the table there will be only 3 fields user can edit itself rather than going to another page so what I did here placed a button and got the text values of every column within that row and converted to textfield

Below is my code hope anyone can help me out

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit_row', function() {
 var id   = $(this).attr('data-id');
 var field1     = $('fielda'+id).text();
 var field2     = $('fieldb'+id).text();
 var field3     = $('fieldc'+id).text();
 console.log(field1);
 var textField1  = "<input type='text' class='vala"+id+"' value='"+field1+"' />"; 
 var textField2  = "<input type='text' class='valb"+id+"' value='"+field2+"' />"; 
 var textField3  = "<input type='text' class='valc"+id+"' value='"+field3+"' />"; 
 $('fielda'+id).html(textField1);
 $('fieldb'+id).html(textField2);
 $('fieldc'+id).html(textField3);
 $('.inf_act'+id).html("<a class='btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon save_row' data-id='"+id+"'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>Save</a><a class='btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon cancel_row' data-id='"+id+"'><i class='fa fa-times'></i>Cancel</a>");
});

$(document).on('click', '.cancel_row', function() {
 var id   = $(this).attr('data-id');
 var field1     = $('vala'+id).val();
 var field2     = $('valb'+id).val();
 var field3     = $('valc'+id).val();
 $('fielda'+id).html(field1);
 $('fieldb'+id).html(field2);
 $('fieldc'+id).html(field3);
 $('.inf_act'+id).html("<a href='#'><i class='fa fa-upload'></i>Upload</a><a class='btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row' data-id='"+id+"'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i>Edit</a>");
});
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table ">
     <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>EVENTO</th>
      <th>Entro DATA</th>
      <th>RESPONSABILE</th>
      <th>COMMENTI</th>
      <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr class="edRow1">
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="idData[]" /></td>
       <td>Inoltdo gara</td>
       <td class="fielda1">16-Jun</td>
       <td class="fieldb1">Arianna</td>
       <td class="fieldc1">Risposta entdo il 23/6</td>
       <td class="inf_act1"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload</a>
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="edRow2">
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="idData[]" /></td>
       <td>Inoltdo gara</td>
       <td class="fielda2">16-Jun</td>
       <td class="fieldb2">Arianna</td>
       <td class="fieldc2">Risposta entdo il 23/6</td>
       <td class="inf_act2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload</a>
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="edRow3">
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="idData[]" /></td>
       <td>Inoltdo gara</td>
       <td class="fielda3">16-Jun</td>
       <td class="fieldb3">Arianna</td>
       <td class="fieldc3">Risposta entdo il 23/6</td>
       <td class="inf_act3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload</a>
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="edRow4">
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="idData[]" /></td>
       <td>Inoltdo gara</td>
       <td class="fielda4">16-Jun</td>
       <td class="fieldb4">Arianna</td>
       <td class="fieldc4">Risposta entdo il 23/6</td>
       <td class="inf_act4"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload</a>
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="edRow5">
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="idData[]" /></td>
       <td>Inoltdo gara</td>
       <td class="fielda5">16-Jun</td>
       <td class="fieldb5">Arianna</td>
       <td class="fieldc5">Risposta entdo il 23/6</td>
       <td class="inf_act5"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload</a>
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: see the link I have shared the link of working fiddle

Comment: I don't know how to make his link properly visible https://jsfiddle.net/m6o4yugd/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all your `$('fielda'+id)` to `$(this).closest("tr").find('.fielda'+id)` (etc for other fields)

Also changed your save event to be called when `save_row` is clicked not cancel - there's currently no cancel handler.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit_row', function() {
 var id   = $(this).attr('data-id');
 var field1     = $(this).closest("tr").find('.fielda'+id).text();
 var field2     = $(this).closest("tr").find('.fieldb'+id).text();
 var field3     = $(this).closest("tr").find('.fieldc'+id).text();
 console.log(field1);
 var textField1  = "<input type='text' class='vala"+id+"' value='"+field1+"' />"; 
 var textField2  = "<input type='text' class='valb"+id+"' value='"+field2+"' />"; 
 var textField3  = "<input type='text' class='valc"+id+"' value='"+field3+"' />"; 
 $(this).closest("tr").find('.fielda'+id).html(textField1);
 $(this).closest("tr").find('.fieldb'+id).html(textField2);
 $(this).closest("tr").find('.fieldc'+id).html(textField3);
 $(this).closest("tr").find('.inf_act'+id).html("<a class='btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon save_row' data-id='"+id+"'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>Save</a><a class='btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon cancel_row' data-id='"+id+"'><i class='fa fa-times'></i>Cancel</a>");
});

$(document).on('click', '.save_row', function() {
 var id   = $(this).attr('data-id');
 var field1     = $(this).closest("tr").find('.vala'+id).val();
 var field2     = $(this).closest("tr").find('.valb'+id).val();
 var field3     = $(this).closest("tr").find('.valc'+id).val();
 $(this).closest("tr").find('.fielda'+id).html(field1);
 $(this).closest("tr").find('.fieldb'+id).html(field2);
 $(this).closest("tr").find('.fieldc'+id).html(field3);
 $(this).closest("tr").find('.inf_act'+id).html("<a href='#'><i class='fa fa-upload'></i>Upload</a><a class='btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row' data-id='"+id+"'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i>Edit</a>");
});
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table ">
     <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>EVENTO</th>
      <th>Entro DATA</th>
      <th>RESPONSABILE</th>
      <th>COMMENTI</th>
      <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr class="edRow1">
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="idData[]" /></td>
       <td>Inoltdo gara</td>
       <td class="fielda1">16-Jun</td>
       <td class="fieldb1">Arianna</td>
       <td class="fieldc1">Risposta entdo il 23/6</td>
       <td class="inf_act1"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload</a>
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="edRow2">
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="idData[]" /></td>
       <td>Inoltdo gara</td>
       <td class="fielda2">16-Jun</td>
       <td class="fieldb2">Arianna</td>
       <td class="fieldc2">Risposta entdo il 23/6</td>
       <td class="inf_act2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload</a>
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="edRow3">
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="idData[]" /></td>
       <td>Inoltdo gara</td>
       <td class="fielda3">16-Jun</td>
       <td class="fieldb3">Arianna</td>
       <td class="fieldc3">Risposta entdo il 23/6</td>
       <td class="inf_act3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload</a>
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="edRow4">
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="idData[]" /></td>
       <td>Inoltdo gara</td>
       <td class="fielda4">16-Jun</td>
       <td class="fieldb4">Arianna</td>
       <td class="fieldc4">Risposta entdo il 23/6</td>
       <td class="inf_act4"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload</a>
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="edRow5">
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="idData[]" /></td>
       <td>Inoltdo gara</td>
       <td class="fielda5">16-Jun</td>
       <td class="fieldb5">Arianna</td>
       <td class="fieldc5">Risposta entdo il 23/6</td>
       <td class="inf_act5"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload</a>
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right mleft5 btn-icon edit_row" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```